# How to setup BlackBerry Phonegap project in Eclipse -- MyApp.java to load index.html?

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, cordova

**Question:** *How does one properly initialize a phonegap project for BlackBerry in Eclipse?*

**Details:** I have my project files added to the new Eclipse BlackBerry Project and added the Phonegap lib to the build paths, however I cannot seem to figure out how to connect the MyApp.java to the index.html to run the project as a phonegap/web app.

**Setup:** I believe I have all of the pre-reqs taken care of: Java JDK/JRE, Eclipse, BlackBerry WebWorks SDK, BB WW SDK plug-in and JRE's for Eclipse, phonegap libs & files, and my project files. I have created a new BlackBerry project and added my files to it and configured the build path.

**Background:** I have developed several apps for iOS and Android already and a client has asked me to develop one for BlackBerry (using phonegap/callback). I've used phonegap with Eclipse for Android without any problems, but I am having a heck of a time getting it setup properly for BlackBerry.

**Research:** I have spent the past 2 days looking all over stackoverflow, phonegap wiki, blackberry forums, and everywhere google could take me and I cannot find anything relevant or helpful. It seems BlackBerry has recently changed their development tools and/or SDK and plugins. Most of the tutorials that would seem helpful refer to a BlackBerry Eclipse plug-in that is no longer available (which would allow one to create "BlackBerry Widget" projects). I have found numerous links to pages on BlackBerry's website that others site and/or refer to but only result in 404's. I've about had it with BlackBerry!

**Thanks in advance for any help you may offer.**

Comment: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-BlackBerry-WebWorks may this help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK Finally found a workable Answer.

Now that PhoneGap (or rather "Callback" as it is now called) has updated to version 1.2 they finally updated their documentation. They have a guide on their wiki that has new and current info to configure eclipse to build BlackBerry projects for PhoneGap/Callback.

Here is the guide (note this is for BB OS 4.*): http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/25653281/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap-BlackBerry%20with%20the%20Latest%20Environment

(I printed a copy to PDF just in case... For some reason a lot of BlackBerry related links/guides seem to disappear)

Also, you can no longer build phonegap projects for BlackBerry using Eclipse for BB OS 5.0+ (unless of course you have the old plugin still installed in Eclipse, which has been unavailable for install/update since October 18, 2011)

The only way I can find to make PhoneGap BlackBerry projects for BB OS 5.0+ Is here: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20BlackBerry%20WebWorks (ignore the last part about Eclipse as it's out dated)

Answer (score 3):

1. Install BlackBerry Java Plug-in 1.3.0
2. BB WebWorks update site : http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/web
3. Create a project and the structure should look like this

[image]

4. Open config.xml and give your url to index.html page in foreground start page option
   [image]
5. Build, sign and run.

Enjoy.

Comment: I appreciate the response and the screenshots, very helpful.
However, I tried previously and just tried again to install the WebWorks plugin you listed, but to no avail. It will accept the url and even list the 2 packages to install, but when I proceed it gives me the following error(s):
----------------
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in 2.5.1.201010291444-2 (net.rim.browser.tools.feature.feature.group 2.5.1.201010291444-2)
----------------
Same for BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.0.0.20110323...

Comment: I also would like to know: how does config.xml work with the BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml? Though I suppose that is a different project setup because the only plugin I could install for BlackBerry was http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java (similar to the location you posted Neel, but with "java" instead of "web")

Comment: nice explain Neel, i am getting this error while installing BB Updated Error : Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in 2.5.1.201010291444-2 (net.rim.browser.tools.feature.feature.group 2.5.1.201010291444-2)
  Missing requirement: BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in 2.5.1.201010291444-2 (net.rim.browser.tools.feature.feature.group 2.5.1.201010291444-2) requires 'org.eclipse.ui.ide [3.6.0,3.7.0)' but it could not be found

Comment: @Neel -- Your guide works if you already have the discontinued BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in. It wouldn't work for me because I got to it after they discontinued it and thus I'm out of luck. Thank you for your help though.

-- I found a quote: _"End Of Life Notice: The BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in will no longer be available for download as of Oct. 18, 2011. Support for the plug-in will be discontinued on Dec. 31, 2011."_ here: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20BlackBerry%20WebWorks#InstalltheBlackBerryWebandWebWorksSDKPluginsforEclipse

Comment: @AjayPatel you are getting that error because BlackBerry discontinued the plug-in as of Oct. 18th, 2011 (see link in my comment to Neel above).

Comment: @mason81 Then after i tried the same with Eclipse Heloise, and it works

Comment: @AjayPatel.. i have asked you to install BlackBerry Java Plug-in 1.3.0. which comes with Eclipse Heloise. at first step.